# jquery: access internal functions from outside the plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-1.9

I have some local functions that I put inside a plugin's method, and I wonder if I can access the plugin's method's function from outside?

This is my code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.fn.hilight.init.plugins();
});

(function ($) {

    var pluginName = 'hilight';

    var methods = {

        init: function(options){

            var base = this;

                    // Method's function.
            base.plugins = function() {
                alert("an internal function");
            }

            var o = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.hilight.defaults, options );

        }
    }

    $.fn[pluginName] = function( method ) {

        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );  // always change 'init' to something else if you different method name.
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.plugin' );
        }

        return this; 

    };

    $.fn[pluginName].defaults = {
        foreground: "red",
        background: "yellow"
    }


}( jQuery ));
```

But I get an error of course,

> TypeError: $.fn.hilight.init is undefined [Break On This Error]
>
> $.fn.hilight.init.plugins();

Any ideas how I can achieve that?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GD6wA/2/)

Comment: Sometime It depends on browser. Guess in Chrome you can access it, in Firefox not.

Comment: Please pay no attention to the previous comment - it could not be more incorrect!!!

Comment: thanks Archer for pointing it out! :D

Comment: This may be a stupid comment, but what if you do $.fn.hilight.methods.init.plugins(); ?

Comment: nah, it won't work...